# Create and download PDF (client side)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, pdf

I need to Create PDF template with HTML and CSS and when user click on some button, download PDF that includes images Link from APIs (client side / React.js)

I use this for Create PDF: `jspdf` `html2canvas`

every thing is ok but my main problem is when is use `img` tag in my pdf template and put API `img` link into `src` of that `img` tag, when user download pdf, img don't show in pdf **(but when i use local images, every thing is working correctly)**

how can i solve this?

and this is my code :

```js
import React from 'react';
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';

// Assets
import Logo from '../Svg/Logo';
import './pdf.scss';

const printDocument = () => {
    const input = document.getElementById('divToPrint');
    html2canvas(input, { scale: 1 }).then(canvas => {
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        const pdf = new jsPDF({
            orientation: 'landscape',
        });
        const imgWidth = 280;
        const pageHeight = 290;
        const imgHeight = (canvas.height * imgWidth) / canvas.width;
        let heightLeft = imgHeight;
        let position = 0;

        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
        heightLeft -= pageHeight;

        while (heightLeft >= 0) {
            position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
            pdf.addPage();
            pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
            heightLeft -= pageHeight;
        }
        pdf.save('Result.pdf');
    });
};

function PdfDownloadComponent({ result }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <div id='divToPrint'>
                <Logo />
                <div className='content'>
                    <div className='side_content'>
                        <div className='details_row'>You Should</div>
                        {/* my content */}
                        <div className='details_row'>
                            <img src={result?.left_eye_request?.image} alt='' />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div
                onClick={() => {
                    printDocument();
                }}
            >
                Download PDF File
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default PdfDownloadComponent;
```